# How do I get Aptana/Firefox to execute my JavaScript rather than show the code?

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to coding and I'm reading a book on it. And I think I have the basics down on this little test project I'm doing, but whenever I test the page I just see the code I used. Here's the entirety of my code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">;
    //<![CDATA[
    // from concat.html

    var person = "" ;
    person = prompt( "What is your name?") ;
    alert("Hi there, ") + person + "!");
    //]]>
</script>
```

Honestly I don't know what the CDATA is for or what concat.html is.

How can I get Firefox to run my JavaScript rather than just show the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in `<html>` to make the whole page get treated as HTML. Does the file have a .js extention, by any chance?

[CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is to distinguish code from markup.

Comment: I'm making this file from scratch, I believe it was started as a .js though, I'll double check to make sure.  Thanks a ton for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an HTML file.

So, first, save it as scriptname.html - you're embedding JavaScript within an HTML file.

Next, make it valid html - add `<html>` to the top and `</html>` to the bottom.  And `<head>` and `<body>` tags where appropriate - if you don't know what those are, head over to any HTML site to look them up (www.diveintohtml5.org is nice, if you can follow it.)

Answer (score 0):

Better install Firebug plugin for Firefox or use other browser's Javascript console. It will allow you to run your code 
http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/execute-JavaScript-on-the-fly-with-Firebug.php